# Need help in transformation logic of Javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have an JS array of objects as below:

```
[
  {
     key1:"value1",
     key2:"value2",
     key3:"value3"
  }, 
  {
     key1:"value1",
     key2_updated:"value2_updated",
     key3_updated:"value3_updated"
  }
]
```

Post transformation , it must be of type object as below:

```
{
   value1: {
      key2:"value2",
      key3:"value3",
      key2_updated:"value2_updated",
      key3_updated:"value3_updated"
   }
}
```

Notice In array , first key-value of each object is same and hence i wanted to merge them and create new object with value1:mergecontent and if it is not same ,, then create new k-v in same object.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We want you to show us what you already tried, and give us a proper problem description along with it. This is not a code-writing service, where you just drop off your requirement, and someone has to make it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the array of object by `key1` first, then assign the attributes

```js
var data = [
  {
     key1:"value1",
     key2:"value2",
     key3:"value3"
  }, 
  {
     key1:"value1",
     key2_updated:"value2_updated",
     key3_updated:"value3_updated"
  },
  {
     key1:"value2",
     key2_updated:"value2_updated",
     key3_updated:"value3_updated"
  }
];

var result = data.reduce((x, v) => {
  x[v.key1] = x[v.key1] || {}
  const { key1, ...res } = v
  x[v.key1] = Object.assign(x[v.key1], res)
  return x
}, {})

var newResult = data.reduce((x, v) => {
  x[v.key1] = x[v.key1] || {}
  const { key1, ...res } = v
  var newObj = {}
  var currentKey
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(res)) {
    if (currentKey) {
      newObj[currentKey] = value;
      currentKey = null;
    } else {
      newObj[value] = "";
      currentKey = value
    }
  }
  x[v.key1] = Object.assign(x[v.key1], newObj)
  return x
}, {})


function transform(d, k){
    return d.reduce((x, v) => {
      x[v[k]] = x[v[k]] || {}
      const { key1, ...res } = v
      var newObj = {}
      var currentKey
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(res)) {
        if (currentKey) {
          newObj[currentKey] = value;
          currentKey = null;
        } else {
          newObj[value] = "";
          currentKey = value
        }
      }
      x[v[k]] = Object.assign(x[v[k]], newObj)
      return x
    }, {})
    
  }
  
  console.log(transform(data, "key1"))
```

Comment: Assuming data which points to array has each object with keys only (key1,key2,key3 ) always

Comment: how if you get only odd total of attribute? it will miss the value

Comment: Key in each JS object inside array are fixed and each JS object has these 3 keys. Now I put check on key1 , if two or multiple objects "key1" points to same value, club them together (where "key2 value" will become key and "key3 value" will become value for it for clubbing purpose)

Comment: THanks much .Thats what i was looking for .

Comment: please mark my answer if it solves your problem, it will help other to know that the problem has been solved ;) Happy coding!

Comment: i want to put this logic in a method with parameter as key1. But I am not getting the expected result once I put this logic in method because while calling the method , i need to pass key1 and I am sending this as string ' key1' . Can you please guide me how can i put this logic in a method and accept 1 param which is key1 because mychecks are on key1.

Comment: please share what you have done, so I can help you easily

Comment: Does this line  const { key1, ...res } = v , should not be changed to  const { k, ...res } = v and when i changed this  const { k, ...res } = v , my function is not compiling in typescript (i consider any JS file is valid TS also) and if i dont change, I don't get expected result

Comment: [
  {
    "key1": "mine",
    "name": "timezone",
    "value": "asia"
  },
  {
    "key1": "mine",
    "name": "okkk",
    "value": "okkkkkkk"
  },
   {
    "key1": "newmine",
    "name": "hi",
    "value": "hello"
  }
]

THis is the dataset i tried .

Comment: no, you can't change to `const { k, ...res } = v` because you does not have key `k` in your `v` object